# Null Pointer exception. Can't figure out how to fix

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-logcat

Ok I have a simple main activity that just presents the user with a button to click on and I will add more buttons later.
When I go to compile it compiles but it force closes immediately on my device.

Heres my Activity code followed by my logcat output.

```
package com.michaelpeerman.probability;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.michaelpeerman.probability.R;
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
{
  View.OnClickListener buttonhandler = new View.OnClickListener()
  {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      Intent localIntent;
      switch (v.getId())
      {
      case R.id.cointoss:

        localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CoinActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
        break;

      }
    }
  };

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tracker.trackPageView("/ApplicationHomeScreen");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button localButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cointoss);
    //Button localButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doctor10);
    //Button localButton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doctor11);
    localButton1.setOnClickListener(this.buttonhandler);
    //localButton2.setOnClickListener(this.buttonhandler);
    //localButton3.setOnClickListener(this.buttonhandler);
  }





}
```

Heres My LogCat Output.

```
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.michaelpeerman.probability/com.michaelpeerman.probability.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at com.michaelpeerman.probability.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-08 18:29:12.664: E/AndroidRuntime(6467):     ... 11 more
```

Heres base Activity

```
package com.michaelpeerman.probability;


import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
private String donate_link = "market://details?id=com.michaelpeerman.donate";
private String rate_link = "market://details?id=com.michaelpeerman.probability";
private String more_apps = "market://search?q=pub:Michael Peerman";
private String sharetext = "Check out this amazing Probability app." + "\n"
        + "\n" + "http://goo.gl/yU3jy";
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    tracker.startNewSession("REMOVED", 60, this);
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.donate:
        tracker.trackEvent("Menu_Item", "donate", "clicked", 0);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(donate_link)));
        break;
    case R.id.rate:
        tracker.trackEvent("Menu_Item", "rate", "clicked", 0);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rate_link)));
        break;
    case R.id.moreapps:
        tracker.trackEvent("Menu_Item", "more_apps", "clicked", 0);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(more_apps)));
        break;
    case R.id.share:
        tracker.trackEvent("Menu_Item", "share", "clicked", 0);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent
                .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharetext);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     tracker.dispatch();


 }
@Override
 public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     tracker.dispatch();
     tracker.stopSession();

 }
}
```

And heres Main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TableRow 
        android:background="@drawable/coin_toss_banner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableRow>
   <Button android:id="@+id/cointoss"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Coin Toss" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like findViewById() is not finding the button.  Double check your XML to make sure that id is assigned properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This has nothing to do with main.xml or the Button. The following line is throwing the null pointer:

```
tracker.trackPageView("/ApplicationHomeScreen");
```

Looking at `BaseActivity` there is no access modifier specified for `tracker`, so it takes on the default access modifier, which apparently does not allow access to inheriting classes, **even if they're in the same package**. Looking at your code, the two classes do seem to be in the same package. Regardless, explicitly defining `tracker` as `protected` will allow it to be accessed from inheriting classes, regardless of package.

I'm still a little stumped by this. As far as I'm concerned it shouldn't have compiled. Somehow the tracker variable is accessible, but the instantiation of it is not...any Java experts lurking to shed some light?

Comment: Can you try declaring tracker as protected?

Comment: Ok it works now. Can you explain what that does and update your answer and ill accept it.

Comment: I'm a little confused myself, I update the answer to the best of my ability :)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `tracker` is, it hasn't been initialized.  I see you have a base class you're extending, so make sure that `tracker` has been set up properly in the superclass.  That means either in a constructor or `super.onCreate()`.

Comment: The tracker is intialized in base Activity I have updated the question to contain the base class